# Why concatenation of images in moviepy fails sometimes?

Tags: python, animation, moviepy

I use the following code to read two images, set their duration and concatenate them into one animation.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

ic_1 = ImageClip('pg_0.png')
ic_1 = ic_1.set_duration(2.0)

ic_2 = ImageClip('pg_1.png')
ic_2 = ic_2.set_duration(2.0)

video = concatenate([ic_1, ic_2], method="compose")
video.write_videofile('test.avi', fps=24, codec='mpeg4')
```

It works as expected for `pg_0.png` and `pg_1.png`. But f I replace these two images by another two images I get an error message:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (272,363,3) (272,363)
```

If more details are needed, here is the complete message:

```
[MoviePy] >>>> Building video test.avi
[MoviePy] Writing video test.avi
|----------| 0/97   0% [elapsed: 00:00 left: ?, ? iters/sec]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    video.write_videofile('test.avi', fps=24, codec='mpeg4')
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 137, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 339, in write_videofile
    ffmpeg_params=ffmpeg_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 204, in ffmpeg_write_video
    fps=fps, dtype="uint8"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tqdm.py", line 78, in tqdm
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 473, in generator
    frame = self.get_frame(t)
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.py", line 110, in make_frame
    f = c.blit_on(f, t)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 571, in blit_on
    return blit(img, picture, pos, mask=mask, ismask=self.ismask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/video/tools/drawing.py", line 45, in blit
    new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2] = blitted
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (272,363,3) (272,363)
```

Why shapes are different? All images that I use look to me as normal png images. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like your first image is a 3D array, whereas your second is a 2D array. Can you show the code to load the images and the images themself? Maybe the first image is has color whereas the second is grayscale?

Comment: I agree with @syntonym, you should provide the pictures that cause the bug, so that it could be fixed.